# SQL creating rollback trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to create application on VB.net ( I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio) which checks whether entered value (Amount) is > (Available Amount) and if answer is yes I should get ROLLBACK + message which should include item name. Things that doesn't work:

- Message  that returns Name from view (Orders)
- Somehow whenever I enter available value or not, the trigger still occurs, maybe I've done some mistakes, here's the code:

  ```
  IF EXISTS (SELECT Quantity
             FROM Products a, Orders b
             WHERE b.Amount > a.Quantity
        ) 
      BEGIN
      RAISERROR ('----There is not enough items left----', 16, 1);
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
      RETURN  
      END
  GO
  ```

Comment: you don't appear to be attempting to relate the `Products` and `Orders` tables. Do both of them only consist of a *single* row? If not, shouldn't they have some form of common column to relate them (maybe, say, a `ProductID`)?

Comment: YES, good notice. It fixed the error. Any suggestion how do I get ProductName from Orders View for instance? So that it would show product name in the error?